# Video freezes randomly in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I have an application that plays many downloaded .mp4 files in an AVPlayer (not streaming). Occasionally, a random video will freeze in a random place (audio and video stops). I can still interact with the screen (I have a custom UI for controls), and I can hit a pause/play button, but it says frozen. I am observing/printing the AVPlayer rate, and the AVPlayerItem status... but they remain at 1.0 and readyToPlay (the rate changes to 0.0 if I hit "pause", then back to 1.0 when i hit "play"). Since the files are downloaded locally, there is no buffering (that I am aware of). The weirdest part is that if I put the app in the background (go to the iPhone homescreen), and re-open the app after a couple seconds, the video continues playing no-problem. What is going on here?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I'm having the exact same issue, even noticing the video resuming when backgrounding/resuming the app. Rate always shows 1.0 and the status is .readyToPlay. Difference in my case is I'm streaming an m3u8 URL, so this might not be just related to streaming a local mp4 in your case